# Creating ring using overlapping and fully contained polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, overlapping-features, ring

How do I use the middle polygon to cut a ring in the bigger polygon without
moving the middle polygon to another layer in QGIS 3.30?

[image: over lapping polygons]

I think there is a way to make this edit in-place without having them on two separate layers. When I select them both and use "Difference" or "Symmetrical Difference" they disappear. Do they really have to be on different layers?

Answer (score 5):

1. Select your polygon which must be edited:

   [image]

   editable polygon is already selected in the picture
2. Edit-> Edit Geometry -> Add Ring

   [image]
3. Make sure that the snapping option is switched on

   [image]

   Snapping options window:

   [image]
4. Digitize the smaller polygon (whole) and click the left mouse key to finish ring digitizing and make a ring. At the end, you will get an edited polygon.

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a native QGIS Processing Tool that does what you are looking for.

But some time ago, I wrote a processing script for this. "Conditional Difference" is part of the [ProcessX-PlugIn](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/).

Set it up the following:

- as predicate choose intersects
- as order by expression use the default setting or simply `$area`
- as order by method choose descending
- choose your layer as source and overlay input

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Having both input polygons on the same layer, you can use the function [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) to identify polygons that are completely contained within other ones and create the difference between the larger polygon and the smaller one contained in it.

Use [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) to get the visualization only on your initial layer or run [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) to get the result as actual geometries, but on another layer ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

Use this expression (in QGIS versions older than 3.28, use [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry) instead of `@geometry`):

```
difference (
    @geometry, 
    overlay_contains(
        @layer, 
        @geometry
    )[0]
)
```

*Screenshot, showing the solution with Geometry generator: the blue hached area is created with the expression:*
[image]